# Change footer in JQPrint

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2, jqprint

I'm using [JQPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) to print a specific `div` on my page. It sets the footer of the printed page equal to the URL of the page (similar to printing most sites online).

Is there a way I can specify what this footer prints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it's the browser that is adding this footer, not JQPrint and AFAIK you don't have much control over this.

Comment: That's what I figured =/ Didn't know if there was any plugin or anything that existed to change what footer printed from the browser...

Comment: @slandau, no, you cannot control the header and footer added by the browsers when printing unless you use some browser specific extension (like an ActiveX for Internet Explorer for example).